# Eclipse + JavaHL / SVN - ClientException - Ajuda

Tags: eclipse, svn

Quero apenas sincronizar o repositório online do projeto do meu TCC com o Eclipse através da SVN no MAC. Uso o Lion aqui no meu White, já instalei o JavaHL pelo MacPorts, instalei o Subclipse e tudo mas não consigo fazer checkout.

Quando vou em Preferências > Team > SVN me aparece uma mensagem no meio da tela dizendo:

> Failed to load JavaHL Library.
>       These are the errors that were encountered:
>       no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
>       no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
>       Native Library /opt/local/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.0.dylib already loaded in another classloader
>       java.library.path = /Users/AllenFGA/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.

Na minha tela de Preferências > Team > SVN eu tenho dois SVN. O primeiro mostra, na sessão SVN Connector, depois que clica em OK na mensagem acima, **Native JavaHL 1.9.3 r1718519 (SVN 1.9.3)** (sendo essa a única opção se clicar na setinha).
Na outra opção Team > SVN (o segundo) mostra na sessão **SVN Interface JavaHL (JNI) Not Available.** Nesse segundo, se eu clicar na setinha pra aparecer mais opções me é mostrado também **SVNKit (Pure Java) SVNKit v1.8.12.10533.** Mesmo eu deixando SVNKit selecionado ainda não consigo fazer checkout. Ainda assim, se eu deixar selecionado o SVNKit, o erro do começo desaparece, mas não resolve o problema de fazer checkout.

Eu consigo me conectar ao repositório, visualizar as pastas, etc, mas ao dar um checkout para baixar o código para maquina me aparece a mensagem:

> SVN: '0x0040010b: Obtain Project Name' operation finished with error:
>   org/apache/subversion/javahl/ClientException$ErrorMessage
>       org/apache/subversion/javahl/ClientException$ErrorMessage

Se alguém já passou por isso e puder me ajudar, fico no aguardo.

Answer (score 1):

Esse JavaHL não costuma funcionar com o subeclipse porque ele usa o Java Native Interface que nunca funciona! Muda pro connector SVNKit: Para
configurar o connector, vá em: Window, Preferences, aba Team - SVN.
Veja o quadro "SVN Interface" selecione "SVNKit (Pure Java)".
Espero ter ajudado ^^